# Excel VBA Macro merge if column has specific value

Tags: vba, excel

Column A: values not a concern 
Column B: certain number for example B3 may be 3, B4 may be 3, B5 may be 3, B6 may be 4, etc.

I want to be able to merge cells in column A if the adjacent cells in column B are the same
Using the same example, A3-A5 would be merged

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MergeSameValue()

For Each cell In Sheet1.Columns(1).Cells
    If cell.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If cell.Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
        Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, 1)).Merge
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: Hi, thanks so much! I tried running it but it didn't seem to work.